# BQ M10 Ubuntu Touch - Micro HDMI Not Outputting to TV

Tags: sound, ubuntu-touch, hdmi, bq

I'm trying to use my BQ M10 (Ubuntu Touch Tablet) with my 65 inch TV as the display.

I purchased a GE brand "Mini + Micro HDMI to HDMI Adapter" from Walmart today and I have another adapter that allows me to plug in my Logitech K400 Keyboard+touchpad device. I wanted to try out desktop mode on my 65 inch TV.

I have no issues with the Logitech K400; I'm typing this message with it via my BQ M10.

However, I can't get the HDMI to output to the TV.

Anyone else achieved this? Is there something you must do to tell the tablet you want to output audio and video to another device?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, it seems a little picky about what it will connect to. It wouldn't work with my monitor through a HDMI to DVI converter or in my TV through its second HDMI port, which is labled as a HDMI/DVI. It did however work in a different HDMI port (HDMI 1). So this is rather a long way of saying try a different port